# Unhandled error exception with axios even though there is a try and catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, axios

[image]

why axios error is not handled by try catch block?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 2):

You need to add catch block for your axios request.

```
axios.request(foodurl).then(function(response){
   ...code
}).catch(function(err){
   ...handle error here
})
```

this happens because try..catch block will only handle axios error if you await the axios request like this:

```
const response=await axios.request(foodurl);
```